# Javascript if statement executing even when false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I have the following code in one of my react files. Clearly the value of showMentor2 is false, however in the console (shown below), "this still gets called" still gets printed. Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

```
  const showMentor2 = userInfo.isMentor;
  console.log(`This is the value of showMentor2 ${showMentor2}`);
  if (showMentor2) {
    console.log('this still gets called');
 }
```

[image: Console Log Output]

Comment: Could the type of showMentor2 be string?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it if it's a boolean](https://jsbin.com/hetulijofi/edit?js,console). Are you sure [it's not the string `"false"`](https://jsbin.com/cibiqijiqa/1/edit?js,console)?

Comment: Check whether showMentor2 is boolean...   `typeof showMentor2`

Comment: check type of showMentor2 , Is it really of boolean type.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `false` must be a string, that's why it pass the condition check (because `'false'` is a non-empty string)

```js
const showMentor2 = 'false';
console.log(`This is the value of showMentor2 ${showMentor2}`);
if (showMentor2) {
  console.log('this still gets called');
}
```

To handle this safely, cast to String and compare with `'false'`, both will work with either false value of string or boolean

```js
const showMentor2 = String('false') === 'true';
console.log(`This is the value of showMentor2 ${showMentor2}`);
if (showMentor2) {
  console.log('this still gets called');
}
```

```js
const showMentor2 = String(false) === 'true';
console.log(`This is the value of showMentor2 ${showMentor2}`);
if (showMentor2) {
  console.log('this still gets called');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if isMentor is whether a string or not Because it must be a boolean to get your expectation.

you can do the test by this method

```
console.log(typeof userInfo.isMentor);
```